PC-Lint unknown type name __size_t, __wchar_t
I am setting up PC-Lint in TASKING IDE. I keep running into an issue where the C standard libraries are throwing errors for unknown type names of __size_t and __wchar_t.
errors
The path to these standard libs are provided to PC-Lint through the -i option.
std lib includes
All the types are declared as such.
size_t definition
I know I can avoid the error by just adding -d_SIZE_T_DEF to my PC-Lint setup, but I am looking for a reason as to why the types __size_t and __wchar_t just seemingly don't exist and if there was any other way to get around these errors.
I added a couple of #defines to the header where my macros are. (i.e. #define __size_t unsigned int) While this worked, I feel as though I shouldn't have to be doing that since that type is internal to the ctc compiler (or should be).
I also added #define _SIZE_T_DEF 1. This basically skips over size_t, but then the type becomes unavailable.
EDIT
I found the issue. It turns out I was on the right track with the #define __size_t unsigned int. It turns out, in my copiler .lnt file there are defines (-d options) that define some of the other internal types, so I just had to add these ones in as well.

Did you try including <std/types.h>? I think size_t exist in it.

That folder does not exist within TASKING unfortunately. And the unknown type is __size_t, not size_t.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

It turns out I was on the right track with the #define __size_t unsigned int.  Not if you're on a 64-bit system.  Your train just went off the tracks.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, it is not a forum, and please read "[ask]". Then come back and remove your solution and make it an actual answer, please.
